# Unable to attach debugger from VS 2017 to Azure App Service for Web App Bot

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, botframework, azure-webapps

I have deployed my Bot Framework v4 app as a Web App Bot to Azure. I can connect to it in Web Chat in the Azure Portal, but it is crashing when I message it via Twilio.

I am attempting to debug this, but when I try to attach via Visual Studio's Cloud Explorer I get the error in the screenshot. I have also tried attaching directly by using the username and password in my publish profile, but that always results in the breakpoints saying the symbols haven't been loaded once it is connected. When I look at the debug modules, I don't see any pertaining to my bot's dll. This is with the publish profile set to the Debug configuration, so no issue with optimized code.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error during one of my attempts. I ended up removing the current version of code from the web app by using the Kudu Console, restarting the app service and then publish again from VS using the publish profile.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I've tried this a few times but no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Was able to make some progress on debugging by attaching to SITENAME.scm.azurewebsites.net instead of SITENAME.azurewebsites.net.

Doesn't explain why Cloud Explorer still can't connect, but at least unblocks me for now